# How to display broken HTML in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I will try to display the Email content using React. Sometime, I found that there is not closing HTML available.

Currently:

I am setting the HTML content using **dangerouslySetInnerHTML()** method

```
<div
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: this.state.single_mail_data.message
  }}
/>
```

I also find react-render-html package from the Internet. But, Somehow, I have no permission to install any package.

Can anybody help me to display that broken HTML in react?

Thanks

Comment: What data you are trying to display, post your data also.

Comment: @ravibagul91 you may check input on this link https://justpaste.me/vcFg

Comment: @ShivaniPatel do you get any error using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` ?

Comment: No, dangerouslySetInnerHTML() will display HTML content as string when there is any broken HTML present.

Comment: @ShivaniPatel, it is not possible to do a regex for closing tabs and close them all, better you try to get a complete html file, not partially completed. and css is not a programming language. update your profile.

Comment: I am trying to fetch all email from Gmail, Yahoo. And try to display the same email content into my system. That is not in my hand to fetch the complete file. I hope you understand what I am trying to say you.

Comment: @MohanRamalingam I have already tried with DOMParse. Still not working

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, it's not perfect but at least it wont raise errors, you can put the broken html into an iframe `srcDoc`:

```
<iframe title="test" srcDoc="<html><body>Hello, <b><a href='#'>world</b>" />
```

Since it's not fully supported on all browser make sure to add html5 [srcdoc-polyfill](https://github.com/jugglinmike/srcdoc-polyfill).

Comment: can you give me a broken html example?

Comment: so you did put `this.state.single_mail_data.message` in the srcDoc prop right?

Comment: Yes exactly. I put this.state.single_mail_data.message

Answer (score -1):

Seeing to that  would be the CLOSING tag of you string isn't a solution such as checking for the pressence of the desired string justified?

```
if(!this.state.single_mail_data.message.includes("</html>")){
 this.setState(
    {
       single_mail_data : {
         ...this.state.single_mail_data,
         message : message += "</html>"
       } 
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Every time different HTML will be received and that is not compulsory for </html>. It can be applied for any closing tag

Comment: DAY1: *hey, it doesn't have closing `body` tag*. DAY2: *no closing `table` tag*. DAY3: *man, there is no closing `textarea` tag also*. DAY200: *...*(you rewrote whole html page) __you get the point__